# Using `merge` for Upsert

Tags: oracle, merge

Using Oracle, I created the following table:

`create table A(x number, y varchar2(1))`

I then tried to upsert a new row, `(1, 'A')`, i.e. add the row if it does not exist; otherwise update the row whose `x = 1`, but with an `y` value of `A`.

```
merge into A USING DUAL ON (x = 1)
when not matched then
  insert into A (x, y) VALUES (1, 'A')
when matched then
  update A set x=1, y='A'
```

However, it fails with:

> ORA-00926: missing VALUES keyword

Note that the `INSERT` clause runs successfully on its own, i.e. without the `MERGE`:

`insert into A (x, y) VALUES (1, 'A')`

How can I fix this `MERGE` statement?

Answer (score 1):

The following worked in Oracle:

```
merge into A USING DUAL ON (x = 1)
when not matched then
  insert (x, y) VALUES (1, 'A')
when matched then
  update set y='A'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Oracle, but the standard way would be:

```
merge into A 
USING (select * from DUAL) 
    ON (x = 1)
when not matched then
    insert (x, y) VALUES (1, 'A')
when matched then
    update set y='A'
```

I added a SELECT clause in USING and removed A from insert and update.

In the eye of the beholder, but I think:

```
merge into A 
USING (VALUES (1, 'A')) B(x,y) -- You may need SELECT 1,'A' FROM DUAL instead of values (1,'A')
    ON A.x = B.x
when not matched then
    insert (x, y) VALUES (B.x, B.y)
when matched then
    update set A.y=B.y
```

is more elegant. I don't know about Oracle, but in db2 it is more efficient to have the matched clause before the when not matched clause. I.e.:

```
merge into A 
USING (VALUES (1, 'A')) B(x,y) -- You may need SELECT (1,'A') instead of values (1,'A')
    ON A.x = B.x
when matched then
    update set A.y=B.y
when not matched then
    insert (x, y) VALUES (B.x, B.y)
```

Comment: The first fails in Oracle: `SQL Error: ORA-38104: Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated: "X"`

Comment: It's the set x=1, y='A'. I'll fix that

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
drop table a1 purge;
create table a1 (x number , y varchar2(1));
merge into a1
using (select 1 c1, 'A' c2 from dual) d 
    on (a1.x = d.c1)
when not matched then 
    insert (x,y) values (d.c1, d.c2)
when matched then 
    update set y=d.c2;
select * from a1;
```